# Does Vuforia Has an Event flag when Surface is Detected?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

i want to run a script of Loading 3d models at runtime only when surface is recognized , how can i do it in Vuforia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuforia performs Automatic hit tests to detect ground using `PlaneFinderBehaviour` so you can check the result of this test and if it is some thing other than `null` it means ground is detected. You can do it by creating a method like this one:

```
public void Test(HitTestResult result)
{
    if(result !=null)
       Debug.Log(result);
}
```

Then you can register this function to your `Plane Finder Behaviour` like this:

[image]

In conclusion you can change the logic of course but main idea is to check if `Automatic hit test` returns a value. Good luck!

Comment: How to detect the Lost plance Event ? I tried this code but it doesn't sucess
`public void Test(HitTestResult result) { if(result !=null) Surface.Detected=true; else { Surface.Detected=false; } }`

Comment: The thing is `HitTestResult` does not become null when tracking is lost. It just stays the same as last tracked position. Maybe you can solve it by checking last 3 4 results and if they are the same it means tracking is lost.